# tf diff on server items shows local changes not server

Tags: tfs, team-explorer

I am running the TF Diff command to get differences between two branches. I run the following command:
`tf difference $/myVersionControl/Branch1 $/myVersionControl/Branch2 -recursive`
The only differences that show up are the ones in the working directory and only the top level directory. its almost like it does not recursively look inside. What am I doing wrong here? I can get a list of all the diffs if I do it from Team Explorer just fine. I am assuming Team Explorer is using TF Diff under the covers but I could be wrong.
I am using TFS 2008.
If there is a powershell equivalent - that would be perfect because i want to pipe the output and have a few more things to do with these changes.

[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the Compare dialog options that produce the *expected* behavior in VS?

Comment: Is the result of `tf folderdiff $/Branch1 $/Branch2` what you would expect?

Comment: @EdwardThomson No. It shows me just the top level differences that exist in the working folders on my HDD.

Comment: That's pretty unexpected.  One would never expect a server path to look at your working folders, be it with `tf diff` or `tf folderdiff`.  Are your local changes pended?  Or do you have writable file conflicts there?

Comment: All the changes are checked in. The two branches are in different workspaces but i dont think that matters - cause Team Explorer can still find the diffs. I dont think there are any conflicts. I just dont see anything being compared beyond the top level folder. My command line results come back in less than a second, while TE takes about >5 mins.

Comment: OK, I'm still not following - if you don't *have* any local changes, why do you think it's showing the local changes, not the server changes?  Are you not *at* the latest version locally?  `tf diff` defaults to using the workspace version (on the server).

Comment: @EdwardThomson using folderdiff worked. I guess i was using the wrong command and I am convinced now that TE compare uses folderdiff to compare branches (at least in 2008). Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tf folderdiff $/Branch1/ $/Branch2/ -recursive > output.txt

To use the difference command, you must have the Read permission for all specified items set to Allow.